# If $f$ is defined on the Upper-Half Plane and $f(in)=e^{-n},$ find $f(1+i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a bounded analytic function in the upper half plane. Suppose that $f(in)=e^{-n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Find $f(1+i)$ and explain why the value you found is the only one possible.

I don't know how to proceed. I have two ideas, but I don't think they have any hope.
Let $g(z)=f(z)-e^{-z}$. Then $g(in)=0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I cannot apply the identity theorem to $g$ since the limit point of its zero set is $\infty$ which doesn't belong to the upper half-plane.

The other idea was to apply Cayley's transformation $\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ to $g$, but in this case the limit point becomes $1$, which doesn't belong to the boundary of the unit disc. In either case, the identity theorem cannot be applied. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I really don't understand how you get $g(in)=0$ ?

Comment: I meant to put $g(z)=f(z)-e^{iz}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have a small typo in your definition of $g$. Put $g(z)=f(z)-e^{iz}$. Then $g(in)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Furthermore $g$ is bounded on the upper half plane, since
$$|e^{iz}| = |e^{i(x+iy)}| = e^{-y} \le 1. $$
What remains is to exploit the boundedness of $g$. The zeros of a bounded non-zero holomorphic function satisfies [Blaschke's condition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlaschkeCondition.html). If you transfer that condition to the upper half plane (see for example [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122581/blaschke-condition-on-upper-half-plane)) you get
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{Im}\bigg( \frac1{\alpha_j} \bigg) < \infty $$
where $\alpha_j$ are the zeros. In your example, the series diverges, which forces $g$ to vanish identically. Hence $f(1+i)=e^{i(1+i)}$.

As an exercise, show that there are other *unbounded* functions satisifying the conditions.

---

More details: The above isn't quite the full story. For the disc, Blaschke's condition is $\sum_j (1-|\alpha_j|) < \infty$. Using the Cayley transform $z \mapsto (z-i)/(z+i)$ indeed transforms the condition on the upper half-plane to
$$
\sum_j 1 - \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big| < \infty.
$$
For the specific question, we can directly check that
$$
\sum_j 1 - \Big| \frac{ij-i}{ij+i} \Big| =
\sum_j 1 - \Big| \frac{j-1}{j+1} \Big| =
\sum_j \frac{2}{j+1} = \infty.
$$

For the general case, the condition I posted originally is nicer than the one above, but we can check that they are almost equivalent:

First of all,
$$
1 - \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big|^2 = 
\frac{|\alpha_j+i|^2 - |\alpha_j-i|^2}{|\alpha_j+i|}^2 =
\frac{4\operatorname{Im} \alpha_j}{|\alpha_j+i|^2}
$$
and since
$$
1 - \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big|^2 =
\bigg( 1 - \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big| \bigg)
\bigg( 1 + \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big| \bigg)
$$
we see that
$$
1 - \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big| \le
1 - \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big|^2 \le
4\bigg( 1 - \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big| \bigg)
$$
so our series converges if and only if
$$
\sum_j 1 - \Big| \frac{\alpha_j-i}{\alpha_j+i} \Big|^2 = 
\sum_j \frac{4\operatorname{Im} \alpha_j}{|\alpha_j+i|^2} 
$$
does.

Now, this last series converges if and only if:
$$
\sum_{|\alpha_j| < 1} \operatorname{Im}(\alpha_j) < \infty
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{|\alpha_j|\ge 1} \operatorname{Im}\bigg( \frac1{\alpha_j} \bigg) < \infty, 
$$
so for example, if there are only finitely many zeros in the unit disc, the condition I posted originally is enough.

Comment: @@mrf): Sir I have a question .I know the Blaschke's condition in unit circle is $\sum (1-|z_k|)<\infty$, where $\{z_k\}$ is the sequence of zeros of $f$. From this condition I could not deduce the condition for upper half plane, I saw your suggested site but it couldn't help me. If you suggest for this some another site then it is great to me. By the way I want to know the Blaschke's condition for right half ,left half , lower half plane.

Comment: Since $z\to \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps the upper half plane to unit circle , so if we use Blaschke's condition as $\sum 1-\left|\frac{z_k-i}{z_k+i}\right|<\infty$ for upper half plane then can we get the same result ? I think it gives the same result, as the deduction caomes from this transformation. If I am NOT true please tell why we don't get the same result. If we get the same result then it is NOT necessary to remember the different conditions for upper half, lower half,...etc

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 It's not quite the full story. See my update.